# Remote debug Qt app running over EGLFS platform

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, embedded-linux

I am developing a qml application using QtCreator which must be run and debugged over a remote linux machine. The application must be run over eglfs platfrom and hence remote machine does not have X or wayland running.
The GUI must be displayed over the remote machine display and not to be forwarded over ssh tunnel to the local machine.
How can I make it done?

- QtCreator 9.0.0
- Qt 5.15.2
- Both remote and local machines run Linux.

If I don't set any specific settings in QtCreator, by running the application, I get

```
Starting /home/pi/app/app --platform eglfs on RaspberryPi...
Cannot create window: no screens available
```

and if set enable checkbox Forward to local display in Project > Run settings, I'll get the app running on the local display over eglfs platform which I don't want to.